# Finding the limit of $\left( x - \frac{3}{5} \right) e^{1/x} - x$

Tags: calculus, limits

I have to find the limit of the following function: 
$$
 \lim\limits_{x\to\infty}\left( x - \frac{3}{5} \right) e^{1/x} - x.
$$

I have used L'Hospitals rule multiple times and I cannot get the right soultion. (The result is $2/5$).

Comment: Which limit? $x\to -\infty, x\to\infty, x\to 0, x\to 2$?

Comment: limit to both infinities

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint**: Let $y = \dfrac{1}{x} \Rightarrow L =\displaystyle \lim_{y\to 0} \left(\dfrac{1}{y} - \dfrac{3}{5}\right)e^y - \dfrac{1}{y}=\displaystyle \lim_{y \to 0}\dfrac{5e^y-3ye^y-5}{5y}$

Comment: Got it thank youuu sooo much!